# React js + laravel deploy

Tags: reactjs, laravel

So I got reactJs as frontend and Laravel as backend.In local laravel is running on a t.test domain and reactJs is running on localhost:3000 but I want to deploy them now on the same domain on a sharing host.So how can I set this up?Putting laravel in the react or putting reactJs in public folder of laravel will that work?

Comment: Normally you have your react stuff as SPA in your public folder.

Comment: The react stuff are on a folder public after build but laravel has it's own public folder too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since reactJS is frontend and Laravel is Backend, you simply have to put react in the front line. so in an example, if you have `mydomain.com` react can run there directly and then you can let Laravel run on a seperate location. example `backendservice.mydomain.com`.

then configure your url calls from react to the laravel backend.

That is it. you do not need to put them all together. I personally advise you to kep them seperate.

That way, versioning in the future could have a version 1.0 backend and version 2.5 frontend (basically, it becomes simple)

Here is a reference you could use. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/06/crud-app-laravel-react

I hope I was clear enough. if not, am willing to clarify further.

Comment: That's the best idea.Wonder why it didn't occur to me.Thank you so much.

Comment: The stress of work gets the best of all of us. Am glad to help!